# Trouble with Rotated Text

Tags: html, css

After practicing some of the CSS i have been learning i have encountered a problem and despite trying numerous things i cant seem to get what i want. I transformed the text to fit in the grey divs vertically, but i cant seem to get it so the words are all displayed on one line. How do i acheive this? I think once i get that it should be easy to position them centrally.

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DGHlFmn0Hg

Comment: css {white-space: nowrap;} You may play also with word-break: keep-all;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should center the text first using `transform` and absolute positioning. Then just apply the `rotate` transform (around the center point by default):

```
#headline .buttons {
  height:100%;
  width:50px;
  background:#a5a5a5;
  float:right;
  margin-right:3px;
  color:#fff;
  /* add this */
  position:relative;
}

#headline .buttons p {  
  margin:0;    
  text-align:center;    
  position:absolute;
  width:260px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

### [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqofv51t/).

Note that the `width` of the `<p>` element will just fill the width of the containing button which is just small (hence the text wrapping). So you have to set the `width` explicitly as large as possible (it does not really matter) so that the text will span on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Good approach to vertical text that is placed in one line and takes as much vertical space as needed is described in this article: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/

The 1st example there seems to be exactly your case (compact table headers).